# 'Input string was not in a correct format.' when opening new windows from a .NET core app in C# when using assembly version "1.0.0.*"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I recently created a .NET core WPF app with Visual Studio 2019 in C# and changed the assembly version to be auto-generated at the end ("1.0.0.*").

I did this numerous times with WPF apps with no problem, but with .NET core, whenever I try to create a new window from the main one, I get the following error message:

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

The code I use to create the new window is the following (on a button press):

```
About windowHelp = new About();
windowHelp.Owner = this;
windowHelp.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
windowHelp.Show();
```

I did add the following to the .CSPROJ file (using a text editor):

```xml
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
```

Whenever I revert assembly version to "1.0.0.0" everything works fine.

May anyone help me out with this issue please? The goal would be to remove the 'Input string was not in a correct format.' message while keeping the "1.0.0.*" assembly version.

Thank you for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Additional details as requested:

[image]

NOTE: This is where the "*" has been added.

I will get a stack trace.

EDIT: Here is the stack trace:

```
at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
at System.Version.TryParseComponent(ReadOnlySpan`1 component, String componentName, Boolean throwOnFailure, Int32& parsedComponent)
at System.Version.ParseVersion(ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Boolean throwOnFailure)
at System.Version.Parse(String input)
at System.Version..ctor(String version)
at System.Windows.Navigation.BaseUriHelper.GetLoadedAssembly(String assemblyName, String assemblyVersion, String assemblyKey)
at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetResourceManagerWrapper(Uri uri, String& partName, Boolean& isContentFile)
at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetPartCore(Uri uri)
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPartHelper(Uri partUri)
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPart(Uri partUri)
at System.Windows.Application.GetResourceOrContentPart(Uri uri)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at REDACTED.Help.InitializeComponent() in REDACTED\Help.xaml:line 1
at REDACTED.Help..ctor() in REDACTED\Help.xaml.cs:line 22
at REDACTED.MainWindow.buttonHelp_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in REDACTED\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 153
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at REDACTED.App.Main()
```

EDIT: Current "About" window:
XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="REDACTED.About"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:REDACTED"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="About" Height="446" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the interface is completely empty:

[image]

EDIT: Current "Help" window:
XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="REDACTED.Help"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:REDACTED"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Help" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Same as the "About" windows, the "Help" one is completely empty:

[image]

Comment: is there a stack trace here? what *method* is throwing this? I'm *guessing* it is actually `Version.Parse(string)` being passed a literal that still has a `*` in it - in which case: where/how did you define the version with a `*`? (for example, if I try this locally, I get a stack-trace that includes `System.Version.VersionResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String argument)` at the top, and my calling code at the bottom; what does *your* stack trace look like?). Ultimately: you say you "changed the assembly version to be auto-generated at the end" - what **exactly** did you change?

Comment: The "About" window is currently totally empty, I deleted it completely and recreated it in case something was actually hidden on the window.

Comment: Possibly related, https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/22660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproing from [GitHub dotnet/wpf #2517: For non-deterministic builds WPF application crashes on resource dictionary load](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2517), the following `InitializeComponent()` gets generated:

```
public void InitializeComponent()
{
    if (!_contentLoaded)
    {
        _contentLoaded = true;
        base.set_StartupUri(new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/NetCoreWpfNonDeterministic;V1.0.0.*;component/app.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        Application.LoadComponent((object)this, resourceLocater);
    }
}
```

That's a bug. One would suspect the bug to be [around here in `MarkupCompiler.cs#L2606`](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/ac9d1b7a6b0ee7c44fd2875a1174b820b3940619/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationBuildTasks/MS/Internal/MarkupCompiler/MarkupCompiler.cs#L2606), or rather somewhere above it.

This would look like a chicken-and-egg problem, as the Markup Compiler (which transforms XAML into IL) doesn't know the version number of the assembly yet, but I'm not sure about that.

Anyway, not something you can easily fix, other than putting the resource in an assembly that does have a fixed version number.